# how to parse an iinput command line in writting a mini-shell in c

Tags: c

- I wrote the following code for my linux mini-shell assignment and i
  keep getting the following error message.
       - warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ from incompatible pointer type
       - /usr/include/string.h:136:14: note: expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but 
             argument is of type ‘char **’
- cld any one go through it and tell me what is wrong?

The code:

```
int countArgs(char n_args[], ...){
    va_list ap;
    int i, t;
    va_start(ap, n_args);
    for(i=0;t = va_arg(ap, int);i++){ return  t; }
    va_end(ap);
}

char *parse(char buffer[],int num_of_args, char *arguments[])
{ 
    arguments[num_of_args+1]=NULL;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<num_of_args+1;i++){
        do 
        {
            arguments[i]= strtok(buffer, " ");
        }
        while(arguments!=NULL);
    }

    return arguments;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
    char buffer[512];
    char *path = "/bin/";
    while(1)
    {
        //print the prompt
        printf("myShell&gt;");

        //get input
        fgets(buffer, 512, stdin);

        //fork!
        int pid = fork(); //Error checking to see if fork works

        //If pid !=0 then it's the parent
        if(pid!=0)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            //if pid = 0 then we're at teh child
            //Count the number of arguments
            int num_of_args = countArgs(buffer);

            //create an array of pointers for the arguments to be 
            //passed to execcv.
            char *arguments[num_of_args+1];

            //parse the input and arguments will have all the arguments
            // to be passed to the program
            parse(buffer, num_of_args, arguments);                        
            arguments[num_of_args+1] = NULL;

            //This will be the final path to the program that we will pass to execv
            char prog[512];

            //First we copy a /bin/ to prog
            strcpy(prog, path);

            //Then we concancate the program name to /bin/
            //If the program name is ls, then it'll be /bin/ls
            strcat(prog, arguments);

            //pass the prepared arguments to execv and we're done!
            int rv = execv(prog, arguments);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: he forgot to mention what error it is. The code itself is the error? (the following error followed by the code)

Comment: this is the error and so cld u tell me how to fix it and where to look for??                                                         warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ from incompatible pointer type

/usr/include/string.h:136:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) is of type `const char*` but you're trying to pass an array of char pointers.

If you want to add all of your `arguments` array to a string, you should loop through the array, calling `strcat` with a single array item each time.

```
for (i=0; i<num_of_args; i++) {
    strcat(prog, arguments[i]);
}
```

If you want to add a single argument, decide what its array index is and use

```
strcat(prog, arguments[index]);
```

Comment: tnx for the relay but i did the for loop and i got this error message     --warning: return from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a different error.  Your parse function is also wrong - it tries to return a char* array rather than a char*.  Since you don't use the return type here, why not just return void instead?